# How can we view the source of the Grails framework in STS?

Tags: eclipse, spring, grails

I would like to view the source of the Grails framework to check the behavior of, for example:

```
render
redirect
```

I would like to see this in the STS IDE.
Is there an option anywhere to import the Grails source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.
http://www.grails.org/GrailsDevEnvironment